# How to give output filename in DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator dag operator in airflow to export my bigquery external table data to parquet file format with desired number of output files.
But here how to give output file names. At least the filename prefix.
**Below is my code**

```
    export_to_gcs = DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator(
        task_id=f'export_to_gcs_day_{day_num}',
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        body={
            'launchParameter': {
                'containerSpecGcsPath': 'gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/flex/BigQuery_to_Parquet',
                'jobName': f'tivo-export-to-gcs-{run_date}',
                'environment': {
                    'stagingLocation': f'gs://{GCS_BUCKET_NAME}/{STAGING_LOCATION}',
                    'numWorkers': '1',
                    'maxWorkers': '20',
                    'workerRegion': 'us-central1',
                    'serviceAccountEmail': DF_SA_NAME,
                    'machineType': 'n1-standard-4',
                    'ipConfiguration': 'WORKER_IP_PRIVATE',
                    'tempLocation': f'gs://{GCS_BUCKET_NAME}/{TEMP_LOCATION}',
                    'subnetwork': SUBNETWORK,
                    'enableStreamingEngine': False
                },
                'parameters': {
                    'tableRef': f'{PROJECT_ID}:{DATASET_NAME}.native_firehose_table',
                    'bucket': f'gs://{GCS_BUCKET_NAME}/Tivo/site_activity/{run_date}/',
                    'numShards': '25',

                },
            }
        },
        location=REGION_NAME,
        wait_until_finished=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"BigQuery_to_Parquet" template does not allow you to add a prefix. To do that, you would actually need to [download the template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/bigquery-to-parquet)  and create a custom version.

This is the part in the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/v2/bigquery-to-parquet/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/BigQueryToParquet.java) where the files are written:

```
         * Step 2: Write records to Google Cloud Storage as one or more Parquet files
         *         via {@link ParquetIO}.
         */
        .apply(
            "WriteToParquet",
            FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                .via(ParquetIO.sink(schema))
                .to(options.getBucket())
                .withNumShards(options.getNumShards())
                .withSuffix(FILE_SUFFIX));
```

Maybe you can take some inspiration from other template that was actually created supporting a prefix, such as [streaming data generator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/0ab42b80ce6fbe46e8325195831e0a99fbf18adf/v2/streaming-data-generator/README.md#write-to-google-cloud-storage), but keep in mind that its purpose is different, and also is streaming instead of batch.

[StreamingDataGeneratorWriteToGcs.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/0ab42b80ce6fbe46e8325195831e0a99fbf18adf/v2/streaming-data-generator/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/transforms/StreamingDataGeneratorWriteToGcs.java) takes the prefix parameter from the parameters:

```
  /** Converts the fake messages in bytes to json format and writes to a text file. */
  private void writeAsParquet(PCollection<GenericRecord> genericRecords, Schema avroSchema) {
    genericRecords.apply(
        "Write Parquet output",
        FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
            .via(ParquetIO.sink(avroSchema))
            .to(getPipelineOptions().getOutputDirectory())
            .withPrefix(getPipelineOptions().getOutputFilenamePrefix())
            .withSuffix(getPipelineOptions().getOutputType().getFileExtension())
            .withNumShards(getPipelineOptions().getNumShards()));
  }
```

Another option is just to export the files in a very specific folder where they cannot be mixed with any other process and apply a mass renaming in a subsequent task.